# All the permutations that commute with (1 2)(3 4 5) in $S_5$

Tags: permutations

> Determine all the permutations $\sigma \in S_5$ that commute with the permutation $\alpha = (1 \space 2)(3 \space 4 \space 5).$

Comment: Same as [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/245990/find-all-permutations-that-commute-with-omega-1-9-7-10-12-2-54-113-6-8), or [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/922995/find-eight-elements-in-s-6-that-commute-with-123456) etc.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: $\varphi\in S_n$ then
$$\varphi(a_1,a_2,\cdots,a_k)\varphi^{-1}=(\varphi(a_1),\cdots,\varphi(a_k)).$$

Suppose $\varphi\in S_5$ such that $\varphi\sigma \varphi^{-1}=\sigma$ then $\varphi(1)=1,2$ and hence $\varphi(2)=2,1$.

Similarly for $(3,4,5)$.